# Including properties with xpointer in Sulu templates

Tags: php, xml, symfony4, sulu

I have set up some Sulu templates and I have been able to use the method described here to include the contents of an entire file in multiple templates:

https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.1/book/templates.html

I'm using:

`<xi:include href="fragments/common-properties.xml"/`

and this works perfectly

However I have then tried to include the properties from another template using the xpointer method (in order that i can include a bunch of common properties across all templates in one file, PLUS define specific properties for the individual templates)

My root template is here: (root-page-test.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.0.xsd">

    <key>my-account-page-react</key>

    <view>pages/my-account-page-react</view>
    <controller>App\Controller\Headless\HeadlessWebsiteController::indexAction</controller>
    <cacheLifetime>604800</cacheLifetime>

    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Test including properties</title>
    </meta>
    
    <properties>
        <property name="header" type="text_line">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Header</title>
            </meta>
        </property>

        <xi:include href="include.xml"
            xpointer="xmlns(sulu=http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template)
                      xpointer(/sulu:properties/sulu:property)"/>

    </properties>
    
    

    
</template>
```

And the template which contains the properties I want to include is here: (include.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.1.xsd">

    <key>include-test</key>
    
    <view>pages/my-account-page-react</view>
    <controller>App\Controller\Headless\HeadlessWebsiteController::indexAction</controller>
    <cacheLifetime>604800</cacheLifetime>
    
    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Test include</title>
    </meta>
    
    <properties>
        
        <property name="url" type="resource_locator" mandatory="true">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Resourcelocator</title>
            </meta>

            <tag name="sulu.rlp"/>
        </property>
        
        <property name="title" type="text_line" mandatory="true"> 
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Title</title> 
            </meta>
            <params>
                <param name="headline" value="true"/> 
            </params>

            <tag name="sulu.rlp.part"/>
        </property>

        <property name="article" type="text_editor">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Article</title>
            </meta>
        </property>

    </properties>
</template>
```

On loading the admin interface I get the following error from one of the ajax requests:

`[ERROR 1612] XPointer evaluation failed: #xmlns(sulu=http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template)                       xpointer(/sulu:properties/sulu:property) (in C:\xampp\htdocs\<vhost>/config/templates/pages\root-page-test.xml - line 26, column 0)↵[ERROR 1604] could not load include.xml, and no fallback was found (in C:\xampp\htdocs\<vhost>/config/templates/pages\root-page-test.xml - line 26, column 0)↵[ERROR 1871] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude}include': This element is not expected. (in C:\xampp\htdocs\<vhost>/config/templates/pages\root-page-test.xml - line 26, column 0)`

Both files are in the same directory

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPointer is not correct, because if you start it with a `/` it means that you are starting at the root of the document. So if you do `/sulu:properties/sulu:property` the XPointer assumes that there should be a `properties` tag at the root of the file you are trying to include. My suggestion is that you make a file like that ([this is also shown in the last code snippet in our documentation in this heading](/sulu:properties/sulu:property)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<properties xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.1.xsd">
    <property name="url" type="resource_locator" mandatory="true">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Resourcelocator</title>
        </meta>

        <tag name="sulu.rlp"/>
    </property>
        
    <property name="title" type="text_line" mandatory="true"> 
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Title</title> 
        </meta>
        <params>
           <param name="headline" value="true"/> 
        </params>
        <tag name="sulu.rlp.part"/>
    </property>

    <property name="article" type="text_editor">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Article</title>
        </meta>
    </property>
</properties>
```

This way you also get rid of the unnecessary elements like `view` and `controller` tag, which is not needed in this case.

Alternatively you can also adjust the XPointer of your include:

```xml
<xi:include href="include.xml" xpointer="xmlns(sulu=http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template)xpointer(/sulu:template/sulu:properties/sulu:property)" />
```

Mind the additional `sulu:template` at the beginning of the xpointer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. But in my case it was a syntax error in the xpointer definition. I wrote

```
<xi:include
   href="default.xml"
   xpointer="xmlns(sulu=http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template)
             xpointer(/sulu:template/sulu:properties/sulu:property"/>
<!-- _____________________________________________________________^ -->
```

Somehow I forgot the closing bracket at the end of the xpointer attribute.